# Cakephp: Filter overriding model find method. Filter also secondary related models

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, entity-relationship

I have a Group model and a User model. Both extend an AppCompanyModel (that  extends base AppModel).

Relations are:

- Group hasMany User
- User belongsTo Group

I use AppCompanyModel to filter find methods of children models by a common "company_id" field stored into session. So in every page of my site I can see only groups and users related to current company (read during user login, I will call it N) or with a NULL company_id (NULL means that object is usable for all company).

Here a part of my AppCompanyModel class:

```
function find($type = 'first', $query = Array()) {
        $query['conditions'][] = array('OR' => array(
            array($this->alias . '.company_id' => null),
            array($this->alias . '.company_id' => CakeSession::read('Config.company_id'))
        ));
        return parent::find($type, $query);
}
```

When I take the list of groups (for my group/index controller), the query correctly filter every group showing me those with "Group.company_id = N" or "Group.company_id IS NULL", but the referring user lists loaded into groups array include also users that are part of other companies.

This happens because there are some user that have a group with Group.company_id = NULL, but the User.company_id != N. I don't want to see them in my results. 
In fact these are the queries generated from CakePhp engine:

```
SELECT `Group`.`id`, `Group`.`company_id`, `Group`.`name`, `Group`.`description`, `Group`.`parent_id`, `Group`.`created` FROM `xxxxx`.`pro_groups` AS `Group` WHERE ((`Group`.`company_id` IS NULL) OR (`Group`.`company_id` IS NULL))
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`company_id`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`group_id` FROM `xxxxx`.`pro_users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`group_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

How can I automatically use the company filter also for children related queries (obviusly without rewrite every find query depending on AppCompoanyModel)?

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`company_id`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`group_id` FROM `xxxxx`.`pro_users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`group_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) AND ((`User`.`company_id` IS NULL) OR (`User`.`company_id` IS NULL))
```

Comment: just a suggestion: can't you put the additional condition in the `conditions` parameter when defining the [`hasMany`](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany) relationship in the GroupModel? Even if probably you'll have some trouble reading the session variable in your model

Comment: It can be a solution but I would be able to use my generic class AppCompanyModel, and every model that extend it should have the behavior that I asked, without make any change to specific model classes.